# Closing an iTerm tab with multiple split panes

Tags: iterm

iTerm allows you to have multiple split panes open inside the same tab.

How do I close all the panes together and/or the tab housing all of the panes?

The standard close tab shortcut of <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> only closes one pane at a time.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to send command to all panes in tab and then send exit to all of them:

<kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> (send keyboard input to sessions in current tab)

<kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> (exit)

This closes all sessions and tab.

You may want to surpress warning message ("Warning! Keyboard input will be sent to multiple sessions.") for smoother usage.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close all pane in the current tab
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close all tabs in the current window

[image: Menu]